# When do I use "hours" and "o'clock" in a programming document?

Tags: time, programming

When do I have to use *hours* and *o'clock* in a programming document?
For example, I have to show that the program runs at 23:45, should I use *o'clock* or *hours*?

I used *hours* but my manager says that it's not right and I should use *o'clock*?

Which is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

*23:45* is all that is needed here. No disambiguating label like *hours* is required unless there is an obvious risk that the **time of day** *23:45* could be confused with something else, such as the **duration** of an astronomical event.

You would only use *o'clock* when referring to a precise hour and using the 12-hour clock, e.g. *"It is now 11 o'clock".* It would not be normal in most (or possibly any) varieties of English to say *"It's eleven forty-five o'clock"* or — more outlandish still — *"It's twenty-three forty-five o'clock"*.

The label *hours* is usually used when specifying the time in a formal context like radio broadcasting, especially when the 24-hour clock is being used — for instance, when a newsreader says *"It's 23 hours. Here is the news"*, or  when it is necessary to be precise in a military or scientific context (*"The evacuation training starts at 23:45 hours"*).

Comment: To answer your now-deleted supplementary question, "Would it make sense if I write 23:45 hours in the programming terminology as this time refers to the starting time of a program?": you *can* do what you describe, but as I wrote in my answer it is not *necessary* unless there is a risk of mistaking *time of day* for *duration.*